# How to convert a decimal variable to nullable type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following property:

```
public decimal PaidAmount { get; set; }
```

and the following function related to the property:

```
                var PreviousPaidAmount = _db.SEPayments.Where(v => v.Invoice == items).Select(c => c.PaidAmount).FirstOrDefault();
                SEPayment del = _db.SEPayments.Where(a => a.Invoice == items).FirstOrDefault();
                if (PreviousPaidAmount == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    PreviousPaidAmount = _db.SEPayments.Where(v => v.Invoice == items).Select(c => c.PaidAmount).FirstOrDefault();
                    var Paid = del.PaidAmount;
                    Paid -= PreviousPaidAmount;
                    _db.Entry(del).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
```

I want to convert the variable PreviousPaidAmount to a nullable type decimal without making any changes to the property. I am a beginner and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you want `PreviousPaidAmount` to be `Nullable<decimal>`?

Comment: Yes i want it to be nullable without changing the model i.e. the property

Comment: In the Select, cast c.PaidAmount to `decimal?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to change the `Select` calls to:

```
.Select(c => (decimal?)c.PaidAmount)
```

This will make the `Select` call produce an `IEnumerable<decimal?>`, which means that `FirstOrDefault` will produce `null` as the default value, as you desire.

Answer (score -1):

In place of `var PreviousPaidAmount`, please write `decimal? PreviousPaidAmount`.

Happy coding :)